# How do you set ASP.net html control(label) using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have created a JavaScript function to get the type of html control and set it to specified value.

```
function SetControlValue(ctrl, value) {

if (value == undefined)
    return "";

if (document.getElementById(ctrl).type == "text") {
    document.getElementById(ctrl).value = value;
}


else if (document.getElementById(ctrl).type == "label") {

   //document.getElementById(ctrl).innerText = value;
   document.getElementById(ctrl).innerHTML = value;      

} 

return false;

}
```

On my ASPX page i have created a label as below

```
<asp:Label id="lblMessage" class="labels"Font-Size="Medium" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

and now calling the function

```
var don="sample text";

SetControlValue('lblMessage', don)
```

My question is why SetControlValue() function working on text fields but does not work on labels. Is there something that am missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because ASP changes the ID of your label. You'll need to get the client side id of the `label` control.

```
SetControlValue('<%= lblMessage.ClientID %>', value);
```

As @Tim B James suggested in the comments you can also set the ClientIDMode to Static as follows:

```
<asp:Label ClientIDMode="static" id="lblMessage" class="labels" Font-Size="Medium" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Edit: Basically you don't need to check for label or span. Instead you can check if your `div element` has a property called `innerHTML` or `value`. I suggest you to change the javascript function to the following and it should work:

```
function SetControlValue(ctrl, value) {

    if (value == undefined) {
        return "no value set";
    }

    var element = document.getElementById(ctrl);

    if(!element) {
        return "element not found";
    }

    if(element['value'] !== undefined) {
        element['value'] = value;   
    } else if (element['innerHTML'] !== undefined) {
        element['innerHTML'] = value;   
    }

    return false;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dieterg/2Uv4q/)

Comment: Also, to add to this, you can set the `ClientIDMode` of your label to `Static` this will stop asp.net from changing the id.

Comment: Well i tried this it didn't work i was getting this error `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'type' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: plz check my updated answer! try using nodeName instead!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById(ctrl).innerHTML = value;
```

**Update:**

When a `asp.net label` control is rendered it is `Rendered` as `<span>` and not as`label`.

```
    function SetControlValue(msg) {
    document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = msg;
    var control = document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>');
    if (control != null && control.nodeName == "span") {
      alert("its label control");
    }
```

**This works for me!**

**NOTE:** Please make changes in the function according to your needs!

Comment: hi @Angwenyi! plz check the edited answer! and let me know..! it works i have tested it!

Comment: A moment i try it out.

Comment: I get `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'type' of undefined or null reference`on ` var control = document.getElementById('<%= lblMessage.ClientID %>')` I dont know why

Comment: that is what i have mentioned just use the 'nodeName' instead of 'type' it will work!